# Data from usda.gov ends in TypeError: response.data.foods is not iterable

Tags: javascript, iterable

I am trying to get food data in JavaScript from an API (see https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html).

This is my script:

`

```
"use strict"

const axios = require('axios')

axios.get("https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search/", {
    params: {
        api_key: "<MY API_KEY>",
        query: "Apple"
    }
}).then(function(response) {

    for (const food of response.data['foods']) {
        console.log(food['fdsId'] + ": " + food['description'])
    }

}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

`

After I run this in node, I get "TypeError: response.data.foods is not iterable".

To solve the problem I wanted to
`console.log(response.data`
what led to a non-readable output in my console (I work with Visual Studio Code).

Can anyone give me a tip?

Best wishes,

Christian

Comment: The message seems to indicate that `response.data['foods']` is not an array.  So what is it?  When you debug, what actual runtime value do you observe?  Why do you expect it to be an array?

Comment: The description in the API Guide says that foods is an array, see
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/fdcnal/food-data_central_api/1.0.1#/FDC/getFoodsSearch

Comment: You can also use this test with a demo key from usda.gov:
https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=DEMO_KEY&query=Cheddar%20Cheese

Comment: That's all well and good, but what exact value do you observe at runtime when debugging?

Comment: Looks like response.data.foods is an array of objects - check out the response in https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/fdcnal/food-data_central_api/1.0.1#/FDC/getFoodsSearch

Comment: I have tried again with console.log(response.data) and get this output:
data: '\x1F�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03%̱\n' +
      '�0\x14��Oq�\\��N�\n' +
      '�\x04E�\x04�p1�\x1A�I�M[���\rt�8?gm\x00\x04�\x1C�P�VT���*1ܵ���F�\x1E�U\x1FE��_b�q/\x02�0�w\x1609�\x1F,��SJޑ�p�\x021\x10`�w)�U��P\x06
�rb�r�������[��\x01;͓\x18�\x00\x00\x00'

How can I change this in a readable output?

To answer: response.data is obviously a string, thus there can be no array of response.data.foods. That is clear. But why does this work on a webpage and not in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like browsers are sending headers and/or compensating for responses which Axios is not.  So the response isn't JSON, but... something else.

This appears to be [a problem with Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298).  And it *might* only occur on some APIs, not all.  Adding request headers for `Accept` and/or `Accept-Encoding` seems to correct it.  For example this is now working for me:

```
axios.get("https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search/", {
  params: {
    api_key: "<MY API_KEY>",
    query: "Apple"
  },
  headers: {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json'
  }
})
```